# Regular expression ad hoc

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

i'm developing a C# app.

I have a text input field with a submit button.

When I click on the button I want to check if the text is excactly: "CODxxxxx" (x=number).

Actually I have this:

```
if (inputText1.ToLower().Contains("COD") && inputText1.Length.ToString() == "8")
        {
            //DO THINGS
        }
```

but if the string is `xxxCODxx` the statement returns true.

I think regular expressions can help me, but I never used with C#...

Comment: Yes it could - give it a go see what happens

Comment: I want to check if the string's length is 8 chars. The first 3 chars must be "COD" e the last 5 must be numbers.

Comment: So you're checking if a string `StartsWith` COD?.. I'm also surprised that ever works since `ToLower` will never contain `COD`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
inputText1.ToLower().StartsWith("cod") && inputText1.Length == 8
```

Or if you realy want it with regex,
this will be the right pattern:

```
Regex.IsMatch( inputText1, "COD\w{5}");
```

Comment: The `\w` should be `\d` but this definitely isn't a task for regex

Comment: _"CODxxxxx" (x=number)_ - the number validation is missing

Comment: oh yes, you are right... if x should be a number, it must be a \d

Answer (score 1):

Try *regular expression*:

```
 bool correct = Regex.IsMatch(inputText1, "^COD[0-9]{5}$");
```

If you want to ignore case (i.e. `Cod`, `cOD` etc. are supposed to be correct), just add option:

```
 bool correct = Regex.IsMatch(inputText1, "^COD[0-9]{5}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it without RegEx

```
string input = "COD12345";
bool result = input.StartsWith("COD") && input.Skip(3).All(x => char.IsDigit(x)) && input.Length == 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regular expressions:

```
Regex.IsMatch( text, "^COD\\d{5}$");
```

Or your own Solution:

```
string txt = inputText1.ToLower();
if (txt.StartsWith("cod") && txt.Length == "8")
   {
           int a = 0;
           int.TryParse(txt.Substring(3), out a);
            if(a!=0){
            //DO THINGS
          }
   }
```